# estructura multimodulo con maven

Tags: java, maven

Hola buenos días es normal en Maven que al crear un proyecto padre y añadirle módulos se vea así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

si os dais cuenta aparece el proyecto padre pero los módulos hijos se muestran como un proyecto independiente esto es así o es un error?
gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se ve normal la estructura, pero te está dando algún tipo de error en algunas clases quizá por alguna dependencia que falta, trata de compilar el proyecto, cada que clono un repositorio o creo un nuevo proyecto ejecuto este comando mvn clean install y revisar la consola a ver que tipo de error te arroja o por el contrato te debe salir que la aplicación fue construida correctamente

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).